# LikesCount cannot be used in query experssion - REST API

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest

iam tring following query but getting error on "LikesCount". i have Likes column in list . but after executing following query iam getting error on Likes count .
Error is "The field LikesCount" of type "Likes" cannot be used in the query sort expression.

```
var uri= appweburl + "/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/web/Lists/GetByTitle('listName')/items?$select=LikedBy/Title,LikedBy/ID,Title,Id,LikesCount&$expand=LikedBy&$filter=" + selectedFilter + " +'&$orderby=LikesCount desc&@target='" + hostweburl + "'";
```

Comment: What kind of field is LikesCount?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's still weird that `$orderby` does not work with `Likes` and `Calculated` Type columns. So now can do following things.

## Sort them in client side

Ignore `$orderby` from `url`

```
var uri= appweburl + "/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/web/Lists/GetByTitle('listName')/items?$select=LikedBy/Title,LikedBy/ID,Title,Id,LikesCount&$expand=LikedBy&$filter=" + selectedFilter + " +'&@target='" + hostweburl + "'";
```

After getting the response, you can sort using `array.sort()`

```
var sortedResult = response.d.results.sort(function(a, b) {
    return b.LikesCount - a.LikesCount;
});
```

Or using any third party js library. You can use [underscore-min.js](http:////jashkenas.github.io/underscore/underscore-min.js)

```
var sortedResult = _.chain(response.d.results)
                        .sortBy('LikesCount')
                        .reverse()
                        .partition('LikesCount')
                        .flatten()
                        .value();
```

When to use **underscore.js**, find it in the official doc.

> Underscore is a JavaScript library that provides a whole mess of
>   useful functional programming helpers without extending any built-in
>   objects. It’s the answer to the question: “If I sit down in front of a
>   blank HTML page, and want to start being productive immediately, what
>   do I need?” … and the tie to go along with jQuery's tux and Backbone's
>   suspenders.
>
> Underscore provides over 100 functions that support both your favorite
>   workaday functional helpers: map, filter, invoke — as well as more
>   specialized goodies: function binding, javascript templating, creating
>   quick indexes, deep equality testing, and so on.

## Using CAML

You can use CAML to do this. In that case, you have to send **POST** request.

CAML query should look like following:

```
"<View> " + 
 "  <Query> " + 
 "    <OrderBy> " + 
 "      <FieldRef Name=\"LikesCount\" Ascending=\"FALSE\" /> " + 
 "    </OrderBy> " + 
 "    <Where> " + 
 "      <Eq> " + 
 "        <FieldRef Name=\"{FieldName}\" /> " + 
 "        <Value Type=\"Text\">{Value}</Value> " + 
 "      </Eq> " + 
 "    </Where> " + 
 "  </Query> " + 
 "</View> "
```

Request body:

```
var data = {
    query: {
        __metadata: {
            'type': 'SP.CamlQuery'
        },
        ViewXml: query
    }
};
```

Request URL

```
/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/web/Lists/GetByTitle('listName')/getitems?$select=LikedBy/Title,LikedBy/ID,Title,Id,LikesCount&$expand=LikedBy
```

Comment: I wanted to +1 but you went straight for a dependency just to sort.

Comment: It can be done manually. I mean using pure js. That I suggested also!

Comment: I read that as well.  The example isn't laid out that way though. :P

Comment: I like underscore.js for data manipulation than writing by own. It has several utility methods. You can try as well.

Comment: I like `underscore` but I love `lodash`, for obvious reasons.  It'd be nice to see your answer w/o another dependency needed/implied. That's all.

Comment: agreed... answer updated